# Is it possible to make a git submodule only allow updates to commits that have Tag(s)?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project where I enforce, on myself, to tag and "release" a submodule before I can allow the parent to updated. Sometimes I forget and have to retroactively do this. I wonder if there is a way to enforce a rule that a submodule can only update to commits that have been tag'd in the submoduled repo?

Answer (score 0):

There is no really good way to do that directly in the submodule itself (although you can write your own Git hooks to help remind you as you do any work within the submodule).  But you *can* write pre-commit script to remind you whenever you go to make a new commit in the *superproject*.

In your pre-commit hook, you will:

- compare the current commit (`HEAD`) to the proposed new commit (the contents of the index);
- see if any of the changes involve a *gitlink* entry: an index entry whose `mode` is `160000` (i.e., gitlink);
- if so, inspect the corresponding submodule: test whether the commit hash in the superproject index corresponds to a tagged commit in that submodule.

To do the comparison of current-commit-vs-index, run:

```
git diff-index --cached HEAD
```

which produces output similar to this:

```
:100644 100644 ee6fb78cd4a415358558373f176e2bbb7e5e603f 3e4b8b8874e67bda27ebee646c97989e0aa98c5e M      Vagrantfile
:100644 100644 b7ad08494ad84d9d816b7d84f4e75ddf9a6549a2 e12f4afad5e59623b3cf07af459cb1f096c14c25 M      defaults.yml
:100644 100644 9e69570de9caa3e8f1979d9fcf8ad8ddf3992291 c28dd95ca0a7033a224a35302c6ccbbf1612c3a3 M      dev.yml
:100644 100644 e3588c8e7fc19f075f0f83a5e3df3e71e4ee9152 6655fa801bcf442a1b8b8b1a269391cb0807d0bd M      local.yml
```

For each line that has `:160000 160000` (none of the above lines), the old hash is on the left and the new one is on the right, so you can run this through (e.g.) `awk` or use a Python script to find interesting entries.  Note that the file name is separated from the rest of the line by a tab (expanded to spaces above for posting purposes) and if you are using Python or something similarly clever, you might want to add `-z` to the `git diff-index` command to make the output easier to machine-read.  See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index) for details.